# Cleaner way of appending html to an element

Tags: jquery, html

I m working on a infinite scroll as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var page = 1;
        var $ol = $('#namesList');
        var $waypoint = $('#namesWaypoint');

        var opts = { offset: '100%' };
        $waypoint.waypoint(function () {
            console.log('waypoint triggered');
            $waypoint.waypoint('remove');
            $.get('/Home/AjaxPage?page=' + page++, function (data) {
                data.names.forEach(function (name) {
                    $ol.append($('<li class="span3" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">').text(name));
                });
                $waypoint.waypoint(opts);
            });
        }, { offset: '100%' });
    });
</script>
```

See this line :

```
 $ol.append($('<li class="span3" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">').text(THEFOLLOWINGCODEBLOCK));
```

I need to append the following there :

```
<li class="span3" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div>
                        <a href="/Haberler/@item.Id/@Html.URLFriendly((string)@item.Title)">
                            <img src="@item.MainImage.Path?width=260&height=150" alt=""></a><br />
                        <strong class="other_news"><a href="/Haberler/@item.Id/@Html.URLFriendly((string)@item.Title)">@Html.Truncate((string)item.Title, 30)</a></strong>
                        <br />
                        <span class="detail_content">@Html.Truncate((string)item.PreviewText, 75)</span>
                        <br />
                        <span class="detail_content">@item.DatePublished.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

is there a cleaner way of doing this?

should i use jquery tmpl? i dont want to bring in lot of scripts...

Comment: do those `@foo` items need to get substituted with some variable content, too?

Comment: yeah, the data from ajax will be placed there. that s some code from asp.net MVC. just a pasted code. sorry.

Comment: placed there by this code, or pre-filled by the server?

Comment: There are many javascript template libraries.

Comment: Your maintainers will love you for `style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;"` ;)

Comment: @Alnitak i am returning objects as JSON so i d like to populate at the client.

Comment: @jantimon I m the maintainer and loving it:)

Comment: If this works, how much does it matter?  It seems like the bulk of the processing will happen on the client.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs i dont get your point. it is a functionality.

Comment: if seems the bulk of the processing is in filling out the template - the amount of text itself is a red herring.  This question should really be about templates, not merely "appending HTML"

Comment: and to @jantimon's point, why can't you slap that in a CSS class?  That's a pain in the butt to fix later.

Comment: assume that s not there:)

Comment: There is something that could be clarified in this discussion that has some educational value I think. [The CSS best practices article from about.com](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm) provides excellent information on this matter in my opinion, especially about inlining CSS.

Comment: This might belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following, for instance:

```
$('<li></li>')
    .addClass('span3')
    .css({
        'margin-bottom' : '0',
        'more-css' : 'can-be-placed-here'
    })
    // Use either append or html, depending on your circumstance
    .append(YOUR_ELEMENT)
    .html(YOUR_CODE_STRING)
    .appendTo($ol);
```

Or as you mentioned, use some sort of templating engine such as jQuery.tmpl.

Unfortunately, there are no means to perform this cleaner in JS. You should do what you evaluate as most readable and understandable for each case. Above I simply made it more readable by indentation and breaking each instruction to its own line.

As far as templating without an engine goes, you could append the following to your HTML document:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/template">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div>
            <a href="/Haberler/@item.Id/@Html.URLFriendly((string)@item.Title)">
                <img src="@item.MainImage.Path?width=260&height=150" alt=""></a><br />
            <strong class="other_news"><a href="/Haberler/@item.Id/@Html.URLFriendly((string)@item.Title)">@Html.Truncate((string)item.Title, 30)</a></strong>
            <br />
            <span class="detail_content">@Html.Truncate((string)item.PreviewText, 75)</span>
            <br />
            <span class="detail_content">@item.DatePublished.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

And then use it to generate a new element using that markup, like so:

```
var $tpl = $($('#myTemplate').html());
$tpl.find('.detail_content').text('Hai der');
$listItem.append($tpl);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a much cleaner way, but I can suggest a little faster way:

```
var content = '';
data.names.forEach(function (name) {
    content += '<li class="span3" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">' + name + '</li>';
});
$ol.append($(content)); // Call append only once
```

Comment: never ever take the output of `.html()` and throw it back into `.html()` to change the contents of a node.  It'll destroy any meta data (i.e. events) associated with those nodes.

Comment: @Alnitak true, I put it as an alternative :)